# Detect Overlapping Windows

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Is there any way I can detect if windows from my application are overlapping ?

Comment: Check if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473189/multiple-uiviews-overlapping helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the windows in NSApp

```
//find overlaps
for (NSWindow *w in [NSApp windows]) {
   for (NSWindow *w2 in [NSApp windows]) {
      if (CGRectIntersectsRect(w.frame, w2.frame) || CGRectIntersectsRect(w2.frame, w.frame)) {
          // add the pairs w & w2 up in a NSDictionary with w as key and an array of w2s it intersects 
          // ....
      }
   }
}

//handle all the queued overlaps....
```

Comment: Great, thanks ! Is there also a way to get a notification or something when one window intersect another? Maybe rectDidIntersect or something, so it won't have to poll it all the time ?

Comment: well, there are notifications sent when they move or resize. you could sign up for those and then look at the windows when a notification comes in