# Getting a UIView beneath another UIView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have a couple of `UIViews` in the same `superview`. One view which is on top I want to be able to be dragged around the screen while multiple `UIViews` beneath it react when it passes over them (the views on the bottom don't overlap). Right now, I have the draggable-view sending touch events to my `UIViewController` using a delegate protocol which is where I'd like to do all the logic.

Essentially, I'd like to be able to find out what view my draggable view is currently over in the view controller. Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the frames of all your views by walking the subview array of self.view (or your primary view). You can then do a test to see if a particular point is in one of the views, or if there is an intersection of the dragged view's current frame with any of the other frame.

There is a convenience method that lets you do this: CGRectIntersectsRect(r1, r2).

Answer (score 0):

You will want to get the frames of the views and see if they intersect. There is a similar question with example code here [Detecting if UIView is intersecting other UIViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361750/detecting-if-uiview-is-intersecting-other-uiviews)