# How to detect a UIButton in view while dragging another button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have implemented a dragable UIButton in a ViewController.Apart from this dragable button I also have two UIButtons which are supposed to be detected when i drag a Button over them and change the title of static button.How can i achieve this?

this is how dragable button is implemented.

```
@interface ButtonAnimationViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *firstButton; // dragable button
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *oneButton;   //normal button
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *twoButton;   // normal button


@implementation ButtonAnimationViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
 [self.view addSubview:self.firstButton];
 [self.view addSubview:self.oneButton];
 [self.view addSubview:self.twoButton];

UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture 
    = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dragging:)];
[self.firstButton addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture 
    = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dropping:)];
tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[self.oneButton addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
[self.twoButton addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];


 -(void)dragging:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)panGesture {

  if (panGesture.view != self.firstButton)
  {
    return;
  }
   if (panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || 
       panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
  {
    CGPoint delta = [panGesture translationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint center = self.firstButton.center;
    center.x += delta.x;
    center.y += delta.y;
    self.firstButton.center = center;
    [panGesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
  }
    if (panGesture.view == self.oneButton) {
    // I tried this to change the button title.
    NSString *buttonTitle = self.firstButton.titleLabel.text; 
    self.oneButton.titleLabel.text = buttonTitle;
    return;
}
    //if (panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
   // self.firstButton.center = center;                        
    //[panGesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
}
```

Comment: I would solve this using CGRectIntersectsRect(<#CGRect rect1#>, <#CGRect rect2#>). Using panGesture.view and self.oneButton and self.twoButton.

Comment: Also this code doesn't make a lot of sense. The pan gesture is only associated with the firstButton. That initial check will never be true, nor will the last. (ie if (panGesture.view != self.firstButton) and if (panGesture.view == self.oneButton))

Comment: Also to do something when dropping, try to catch the UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded state.

Answer (score 1):

the trick is using [CGRectIntersectsRect](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000955-CH1g-F17158).. that's the basic building block for knowing if one view intersects another. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7369775/766570) for a relevant example of using that function.

here is example code:

```
  if (panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || 
       panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
  {
    CGPoint delta = [panGesture translationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint center = self.firstButton.center;
    center.x += delta.x;
    center.y += delta.y;
    self.firstButton.center = center;
    [panGesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
  }

  // check if there is an overlap
  NSString *draggableButtonTitle = self.firstButton.titleLabel.text;
  if (CGRectIntersectsRect(self.firstButton.frame, self.oneButton.frame)) {
      self.oneButton.titleLabel.text = draggableButtonTitle;
      // i donno if you wanna return here or continue dragging.. up to you
  } else if (CGRectIntersectsRect(self.firstButton.frame, self.twoButton.frame)) {
      self.twoButton.titleLabel.text = draggableButtonTitle;
  }
```

Comment: so basically what u're trying to do is change the title of the button that's been dragged over on the point of overlap right?

Comment: actually i want to replace the title of static button by that of dragable button, when it is draged over.

Comment: Well...I tried that , but my dragable button doesn't seem to drag now.

Comment: that's odd.. i took out the testing code out of the brackets (see my updated code).. try commenting out my code and see if it drags.. i don't see how my code can prevent the dragging.. it's a simple if else statement that updates the title.. see if you've changed anything else..

Comment: also do you need the title change to be instant? if not, you can put it a queue and dispatch_async like dispatch_async(yourCustomQueue, ^{
            // change button title.. 
        });

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGPoint transition = [gesture translationInView:self.view];
        self.dragableButton.center = CGPointMake(self.dragableButton.center.x + transition.x, self.dragableButton.center.y + transition.y);

        CGPoint touchPoint = [gesture locationInView:self.view];
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.hoverButtonA.frame, touchPoint)) {
            self.hoverButtonA.alpha = 0.2;
            //change the title here?
        }
        else {
            self.hoverButtonA.alpha = 1;
            //change the title back to the origin?
        }

        //Same for the other button
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.hoverButtonB.frame, touchPoint)) {
            self.hoverButtonB.alpha = 0.2;
        }
        else {
            self.hoverButtonB.alpha = 1;
        }

        [gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
    }
    //I'll leave out the end part, it pretty much just like the implementation above.
}
```

Only add gestureRecognizer to the `dragableButton`, and why is there two tapGesture, instead of using target action? Besides, One GestureRecognizer can and only can have one view. add it to multiple view will not work.