# how to find if a view touches another view's frame while dragging?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a some movable views in the user interface and I need to know if the moving view's frame touched any of the other view's frame and if touched I need to merge these two views into a single view.

i have added a sample image down here
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361750/detecting-if-uiview-is-intersecting-other-uiviews

Answer (score 1):

You can use`CGRectIntersectsRect` method. Get the bounds of two views and use this method

```
rect1 = self.view1.bounds;
rect2 = self.view2.bounds;

CGRectIntersectsRect(CGRect rect1, CGRect rect2)
```